# python dictionary put values of keys into a list where the keys are in another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary which looks like

```
a = {32: [2230], 37265: [2218], 51: [2223], 164: [2227], 3944: [2224]}
```

however, values in `a` could contain multiple elements, like

```
a = {32: [2200, 2230], 37265: [2201, 2218], 51: [2223], 164: [2227], 3944: [2224]}
```

I have a list that stores the keys in `a` in groups,

```
b = [[32, 51, 164], [3944, 37265]]
```

now I want to get values of keys in each group in another list,

```
        clusters = []
        for key_group in b:
            group = []

            for key in key_group:
                group.extend(a[key])

            if len(group) > 1:
                clusters.append(group)
```

so the final list looks like,

```
clusters = [[2230, 2223, 2227], [2224, 2218]]
```

if `a` contains multiple elements in a value list, `clusters` looks like,

```
clusters = [[2200, 2230, 2223, 2227], [2224, 2201, 2218]]
```

I am wondering what's the best way to do this.

Also in case when `b` contains list(s) which has only one value/key, and if this key maps to a single element list in `a`, this list will be ignored,

```
a = {32: [2200, 2230], 37265: [2201, 2218], 51: [2223], 164: [2227], 3944: [2224]}

b = [[32, 51, 164], [3944], [37265]]
```

while `3944` maps to `[2224]`, which will be ignored, but `37265` maps to `[2201, 2218]`, which will be kept, since `len([2201, 2218]) > 1`. `clusters` will look like the following in this case,

```
clusters = [[2200, 2230, 2223, 2227], [2201, 2218]]
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "best"?

Comment: @PeterWood concise, simpler, more efficient way?

Comment: I edited the answer let me know if that works for you :)

Comment: @DamianLattenero the top 3 answers all work :)

Comment: @daiyue great! I have to practice to give better answer haha...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using a **triple** list comprehension:

```
list(filter(lambda l:len(l) > 1, ([elem for key in lst for elem in a[key]] for lst in b)))
```

This works for list values of arbitrary length. `filter` removes the lists with one or zero elements.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming your values in `a` are always just a list with a single element, then it is a simple nested [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
[[a[k][0] for k in sublist] for sublist in b]
# [[2230, 2223, 2227], [2224, 2218]]
```

Since you've now clarified the values of `a` can be lists with multiple elements, you can use `itertools.chain.from_iterable` to flatten the lists returned and give your desired output:

```
from itertools import chain
[list(chain.from_iterable(a[k] for k in sublist)) for sublist in b]
# [[2200, 2230, 2223, 2227], [2224, 2201, 2218]]
```

Comment: thx for your reply, but values in `a` could contain multiple elements.

Comment: @daiyue can you show the desired output for your `a` with multiple elements

Comment: @Chris_Rands see my op

Comment: @Chris_Rands but the answer should also account for `if len(group) > 1:` as in the code of my op

Comment: @daiyue sorry I don't understand, you'll need to add another example that illustrates the behaviour you want

Comment: @Chris_Rands I have modified my op to add one more example to reflex the meaning of the code.

Comment: @daiyue My answer should address that.

Answer (score 4):

You can use list comp to do the same job:

```
clusters = [[a[key][0] for key in k] for k in b]

res => [[2230, 2223, 2227], [2224, 2218]]
```

if a could have multiple elems, you can do also:

```
clusters = [[it for key in k for it in a[key]] for k in b]

res => [[2200, 2230, 2223, 2227], [2224, 2201, 2218]]
```

Answer (score 2):

According to your edit:

```
[[item for i in sub for item in a[i]] for sub in b]
```